# несуществующий uri nginx wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, uri

Столкнулся с новым для себя методом атаки на веб сайт wordpress, простыми словами, злоумышленник посылает запрос на сайт вида - GET http://example.com/?GJUDISJUgfdjsf
все что идет после знака вопроса "GJUDISJUgfdjsf" имеет случайный набор букв цифр разной длинны, а nginx вместо того что бы отдать 404 станицу, открывает просто главную страницу веб сайта. Но если перейти по ссылке вида - GET http://example.com/blabla где нету знака вопроса в uri, то отдается корректно 404 станица от nginx.

Как с таким бороться? так как этим методом обходят кэширование, и атакуют с множества ip

Comment: 1 Это не атака. 2 Отдаётся индекс и это правильно. 3 А вот 404 от nginx - не правильно. Должна быть 404 ВП.

Comment: это можно как то запретить? ибо этим методом атакуют с разных ип, и как говорю обходят кэш

Comment: Если ты уверен что это боты, и они тебе мешаю(а мешают ли вообще?) то нужно их отсеивать ещё на подлёте, а не ломать нормальную работу сайтов

Comment: Если смысл этой атаки в том, чтобы обойти кеш и завалить сервер, то уберечься сложно. Можно в nginx на главной проверять query (наличие ?blabla) и сразу отдавать 404. Но тогда они будут долбить /wp-admin или wp-login.php.

Comment: @KAGGDesign не то что бы сложно, но может быть затратно - это да. Защита от ДДОСа вполне реальна. Но не думаю что ТСа ддосят, а если и доссят, то как-то по-детски.Наверняка тут тот же f2b поможет. Ну или клоудфларе (хотя я его и терпеть не могу).

Comment: шла именно атака с различных ип, в течении часа, я ограничивал макс конектов с одного айпи, но особо эффекта не дало, ибо как и говорю отдавалась статика из за таких запросов, а не кэш, и именно на главную страницу была атака, еще фишка в том что это все на окне вертится, там нету ф2б

Comment: Сайт на винде... ОМГ... Хотя для виндов существует туёва хуча фаеров.

Comment: nginx на винде это в принципе для сильных духом. Но нем не менее, настроить кеширование что бы оно игнорировала query-параметры вообще-то не очень сложно https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_cache_key

Comment: он и так игнорирует эти несуществующие индексы, и не создает для них кэш, мне нужно именно запретить отдачу реальной страницы на текущий момент если есть кэш главной страницы, ведь он все равно перекидывает на главную страницу вп, когда не находит этот индекс - зловредный запрос.@alexey-ten